# Configurar preloader para que dure hasta mostrar gráfico

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente inconveniente, genero un gráfico de barras con google charts en mi formulario, el preloader funciona bien pero desaparece antes de que aparezca el gráfico que esta en una etiqueta div.
No se si se puede atrasar la desaparición del preloader que he colocado al final del codigo del gráfico, o existe un problema que me falta una etiqueta div.  Adjunto código del preloader y la gráfica

```
    <head>
<style type="text/css">

.loader {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
    background: url('static/images/loader2.gif') 50% 50% no-repeat rgb(249,249,249);
    opacity: .7;
}
  </style>

<script language="javascript">
  function loading(){
    var patente = $("#patente").val();
    var año = $("#año").val();


    if (patente == "" || año == ""){

      return false;
     document.getElementById("loader").style.display = "none";
    }else{
          drawChart();
          $('.loader').fadeIn();

    
  }
}
    
</script>

</head>
```

// los div de loader

```
 <div class="loader" id="loader">
</div>

<button  type="submit" name= "btn2" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn2" onclick="loading()">Consulta</button>

  <div id="barChart"  >  //etiqueta div del grafico


  </div>
```

// funcion para gráficar

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);




function drawChart()
{



 var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
   ['Mes','Litros cargados', {role: 'annotation'}, 'Km',{role: 'annotation'},'Promedio',{role: 'annotation'}],
   <?php

for ($x = 1; $x <= 12; $x = $x + 1) {

    ?>
     ['<?php echo $meses[$x]; ?>', <?php echo $cantidad[$x] ?>,<?php echo $cantidad[$x] ?>,<?php echo $cantidad1[$x] ?>, <?php echo $cantidad1[$x] ?>, <?php echo "100/($cantidad1[$x]/$cantidad[$x])" ?>, <?php echo "100/($cantidad1[$x]/$cantidad[$x])" ?>],
   <?php }?>

   ]);

 var options = {
  title:'CARGA MENSUAL X MOVIL Patente:'+'  '+'<?php echo $patente ?>'+'   '+'Año:'+'<?php echo $anno ?>'
    ,seriesType: 'bars'
    ,series: {3: {type: 'line'}}
    ,legend:{position: 'top', textStyle: {color: 'blue', fontSize: 16}}

  ,width:"100%"
  ,height: 450

};

            // Instantiate and draw the chart.
            var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('barChart'));

            chart.draw(data, options);

          }



          //

          $(window).resize(function(){

        drawChart();

      });
     $('.loader').fadeOut("slow"); // aqui finalizo el loader



 </script>
```

Comment: Podrías escuchar el evento [`ready`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/events#the-ready-event) para quitar la imagen hasta que se cargue la gráfica.

Comment: Perdon, debería ser antes del metodo draw()?